# I cannot run this react app for some reason and I don't know what to do

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg

I have been having difficulty running a react app on my terminal. It was all working fine yesterday until now. I've restarted my computer 3 times, installed yarn, made sure I cd'd into my project folder.

Every time I do yarn start I get several error codes.

I have created file directories, installed webpack, created a react app (`npx create-react-app project-name`) and every time I run it nothing happens. Which is weird because yesterday everything was fine.

Here are some screen shots. What do I do? I can't think of anything else. I've updated npm, I have the latest version of yarn.
[image: package.json]
[image: error screenshot]

Comment: Did you follow each of those steps? I've run into that problem myself a couple of times and the steps have resolved the issue each time.

Comment: Hi Aimme, looks like you have an incompatible version of webpack. In fact, react-app already install it, you dont need to do a manual install of it. Try to follow the 7 steps described in the error and you will probably be able to fix it

Comment: I've tried all those 7 steps multiple times and I still can't run it

Comment: Check if you dont have installed webpack globally. (you can uninstall it with npm -g uninstall webpack)

Comment: I did not work. I feel like I have tried everything. Now it is giving me the error Command failed with exit code 127

Comment: can you add your package.json file in the post, please ?

Comment: ok i added it to the top

Comment: looks good. you are using npm or yarn? I recommend  take a look on global path and see if it has webpack installed also. I think you will have to go through elimination.

Comment: It's literally not working. I'm using yarn but I've tried both npm and yarn. I do not know what to do because I have tried that.

Comment: Did you checked the path? Run this command `yarn global dir`, go to the informed path and see if node_modules contains some folder related to webpack. I know I'm being repetitive, but I'm just trying to help you.

Comment: @AimeeCasden do you have a repo of your project that you can share? If one of us can run it successfully, we can at least eliminate a few things.

Comment: @Yatrix i can't push anything to git either

Comment: @AimeeCasden well...shit. :) You may want to start uninstalling npm, node, git, etc. and start reinstalling. Something is seriously wrong if you can't even commit to git or build a project.

Comment: I figure it out. It was because I had a node_modules folder inside my user directory haha.